# Stubbing Static Factory in CUT with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

My class under test is `ClassA` which in one of its private method uses a static factory (lets say `CarFactory`) method `getCar(XXX xxx)` which returns a `Car`.

Part of the `CarFactory` logic is to validate that the given xxx parameters meets some criteria.

I tried using Mockito like the following:

```
@Mock private Car mockForCar;
@Mock private XXX xxxMock;

...

when(CarFactory.getCar(xxxMock)).thenReturn(mockForCar);
```

But I get an exception regarding that xxxMock isn't valid by the `CarFactory`.

Why is the real `getCar(xxx)` method gets called and not the stubbed one?

Is there a better way doing this?

Comment: look at similar question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito/21111644#21111644

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Mockito FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ):

> **Can I mock static methods?**
>
> No. Mockito prefers object orientation and dependency injection over
>   static, procedural code that is hard to understand & change. If you
>   deal with scary legacy code you can use JMockit or Powermock to mock
>   static methods.

If you want to stub this using Mockito, you should make it non-static and inject the factory.  And that's better OO design anyway.